# CSS fill entire width of div with letters, without changing word spacing

Tags: javascript, html, css

So im working on a kind of password generator and i want the password to be displayed in a div. Everything works fine, except for the word word wrapping. Like usual, the text just gets split at every space if the next word is to long for the current line. But i want css to fill the entire width of the div before starting the next line.

the text `abcdefghij klmnopqrstuvwxyz 01234 56789` is displayed like this
(assuming a line length of 13 characters)

```
+-------------+
|abcdefghij   |
|klmnopqrstuvw|
|xyz 01234    |
|56789        |
+-------------+
```

but should be

```
+-------------+
|abcdefghij kl|
|mnopqrstuvwxy|
|z 01234 56789|
+-------------+
```

basicly all lines should have the same amount of letters in it.

Though i dont want the width of the div to be absolute but rather 80% of the screen width.

I've tried `text-align:justify;` but that just makes the spaces bigger.

Comment: check this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have *the same amount* of letters in line you should use monospace font.

If you also want your lines to break between any two characters - use `word-break: break-all` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break)):

```css
body {
  font-family: Courier New;
}
.container {
  width: 143px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px dashed #333;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}
.container-header {
  padding: 8px;
  height: 16px;
  border-bottom: 2px dashed #333;
}
.container-content {
  padding: 8px;
}
.keep-all {
  word-break: break-all;
}
.break-all {
  word-break: break-all;
}
.break-word {
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container-header">keep-all</div>
  <div class="container-content">
    abcdefghij klmnopqrstuvwxyz 01234 56789    
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="container-header">break-all</div>
  <div class="container-content break-all">
    abcdefghij klmnopqrstuvwxyz 01234 56789    
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="container-header">break-word</div>
  <div class="container-content break-word">
    abcdefghij klmnopqrstuvwxyz 01234 56789    
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the CSS Word Wrap
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap

Comment: that does exactly the top example